# width issue when no data is there

Tags: php, css

I have a section in ma website, which has some width. I load the data by ajax. while loading data by ajax the section does not seem to be seen or displayed, so the whole site layout gets disturbed until data is loaded. So is there a way so that i can make that the width is maintained even if data is there or not.

-updated question to be clear---

i have 2 sections a, b . they are both side by side as i have used float. a's data is loaded by ajax and b has some static data. until a loads with its data, i see b in a's position. which makes whole layout worse.

Comment: What's the link? Or can it be replicated on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the `min-width` for that section (html control)

for an example you can do like

```
min-width:500px;
```

so that html element will have minimum width with 500px even if there is no data